# How to fork Cognito session

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

Is it real to fork current user session?

For example:

We have `domain.com` with currently implemented authentication by `AWS Cognito` service with `Amplify` SDK on the client.

And now we have to move some big part of functional to subdomain `sub.domain.com`.

The main questions are:

- can we have single `signIn` place at `domain.com` for both domains and just implement something like a session fork for `sub.domain.com` (cause if we will just share the same session between domain and subdomain there are some issues might be with `refeshToken`, cause it's disposable)
- what is the best way to share sensitive data between domain and subdomain?

##### UPD: I'd try to explain more clear the logic that I have to implement

1. there are two clients: `domain.com` (already exists) and `sub.domain.com` (the last one will be)
2. authentication is handled by `AWS Cognito` at back and `Amplify SDK` at front
3. `domain.com` and `sub.domain.com` have to share the same `UserPool` and `UserPoolClient`
4. both clients have to communicate with the same endpoints which auth is required
5. client at `sub.domain.com` mustn't have a `signIn` or `signUp` functioanlity
6. but client at `sub.domain.com` still have to maintain and update the session (bacause of 4 step)
7. so business wanna something like this behaviour:

   - if you go to `sub.domain.com` and you are already logged in at `domain.com`, everything is fine (user profile/some private data is shared between these two apps) and user can use app at `sub.domain.com`
   - if a user open `sub.domain.com` but he isn't authorized already at `domain.com`, app at `sub.domain.com` have to detect this and notify user that he have to authorize at `domain.com` at first. And after user did this, `sub.domain.com` will automaticaly get session from `domain.com`
8. **BUT**, if we just share the same session/data from localstorage between two apps, we will have potential issues with refreshing/handling tokens

So, is there might be some various of implementation of this logic such as **session fork**, or something like that?

Comment: Question is unclear. If you need access to the same user pool from 2 different domain/subdomain then you'll need 2 clients defined (one for each) but you cannot access data from one to the other.

Comment: Can the same `User Pool Client` be shared between two different SPA apps with Amplify SDK on domain and subdomain?

Comment: Not a problem. You can have many.

Comment: @grekier
I have just updated the content of the question.
I'd appreciate it if you'd take a look

Comment: Formin Cognito uses cookies so I guess you could add the domain/subdomain in your callback (or cognito trigger) to make it work.

Comment: this still doesn't solve the problem of updating / managing the session.
It just solves the question of how to share data